# Step into static library code in Qt

Tags: qt, step-into

I have a project with the following structure:

```
MainProject.pro
    ExecProject.pro
    LibProject.pro
```

As you can guess there is a dependency between the *ExecProject* and the *LibProject*.

My problem is that when debugging I cannot step into the *LibProject* source code (even if the code is executed).

Here is the *MainProject.pro* file contents :

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += \
    LibProject \
    ExecProject

ExecProject.dependes = LibProject
```

The *LibProject.pro* file content:

```
TARGET = LibProject
TEMPLATE = lib

CONFIG = staticlib

DEFINES += LIBPROJECT_LIBRARY

SOURCES += LibProject.cpp

HEADERS += LibProject.h\
   LibProject_global.h
```

And the *ExecProject.pro* file content:

```
QT       += core

TARGET = ExecProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += ../LibProject
LIBS += -L../LibProject -lLibProject
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Compile it all as one blob when you need to debug it.

Comment: no way to step into static libs?

Comment: I think there may be a trick to recompile the lib with debug info included (the standard compile script for static libs will exclude the info).  But I don't know what it is.

Comment: interesting! I'll try to look in this direction.

Comment: I finally compile it in one blob, making only folder. An *.pro* include would be welcome!

Comment: it seems it exists through *.pri* include... great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem using *.pri* files for my libs and using the following command in my *.pro* file:

```
include(path/to/my/lib/mylib.pri)
```

My project hierarchy is as follow:

```
root
    \app
        \app1
        \app2
    \libs
        \lib1
            - class1.h
            - class1.cpp
            - class2.h
            - class2.cpp
        \lib2
```

Comment: Could you show how have you organized your pri file please?

Comment: @Moia I just edited my answer, feel free if you want to know more!